# Linq to SQL multiple left outer joins

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Ok, I'm a bit desperate here, needs some help. I'm experienced with SQL, but not as experienced with Linq to SQL and EF. I have a proof of concept query that works fine against the DB but when I try to write it against Linq to SQL it doesn't generate what I need.

```
SELECT P.*, C.*, A.*
FROM Parent P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Access A
ON  (A.Field1 IS NULL OR A.Field1 = P.Field1)
AND (A.Field2 IS NULL OR A.Field2 = P.Field2)
AND (A.Field3 IS NULL OR A.Field3 = P.Field3)
AND A.AccessId = 123
LEFT OUTER JOIN Child ON 
C.Id = P.Id
AND A.HasAccess = 1
```

Please note the last line of the first outer join: 
    AND A.AccessId = 123

This is necessary. I must be able to plug in a value here and no where else.

Also notice the last line of the last outer join:
    AND A.HasAccess = 1

Also necessary to control who can see that data.

Finally, the linq looks something like this. Please understand that this is abstracted from the real deal, so I could have some mistakes. I can't post the actual query here.

```
from p in db.Parent
join a in db.Access 
on 123 equals a.AccessId into a1
from a2 in a1.Where(
    w => (!w.Field1.HasValue || w.Field1 == p.Field1)
      && (!w.Field2.HasValue || w.Field2 == p.Field2)
      && (!w.Field3.HasValue || w.Field3 == p.Field3)
).DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in db.Child on p.Id equals c.Id into c1
from c2 in c1.Where(
    w => c.HasAccess.HasValue && c.HasAccess.Value
).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { ... stuff ... }
```

[Edited further to reflect answers elsewhere on SO. Man, this stuff is not intuitive... :/ ]

Naturally, the query that this creates is unnecessarily large, and, for the aforementioned reasons, I can't post it here. So, if someone can help at least get close to the conceptual query, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found the answer to this problem and it wasn't what I thought. My submitted solution above was correct, but a subtle flaw in my logic kept me from realizing that. Unfortunately, I'm now dealing with a new problem. Will post a question for that later.